# A row of Zeros inserting into MySQL database when I insert data

Tags: java, mysql

I am inserting data into MySQL table called comp. The data inserts fine but I get a row of Zeros inserted into the next row. Any idea what might be wrong?

Code for inserting data:

```
    String ret = ERROR;
    Connection con = null;

    try {

        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/golfclub";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into comp values (?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, getName());
        ps.setInt(2, getHandicap());
        ps.setInt(3, getTotalPoints());
        ps.executeUpdate();

            ret = SUCCESS;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ret = ERROR;
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Your code might be executed twice or a trigger could have been configured within your DB. May we know how this code is called ?

Comment: It doesn't seem the behavior is caused by the code you posted. Is the above shown code part of a loop? In case you are using a loop, remember that Java is zero-based, so you may possibly iterate over your code one time too often. Just a guess ...